# submit button can't send action with <a class

Tags: css, html, submit

I am trying to make that submit key works

```
<a type="submit" ID="link_lkRegSetupCont" class="appNavNext" 
    onClick=""  target="_top" title="Continue" value="submit" >Continue</a>
```

It don't work

Here is all my code:

```
<form AUTOCOMPLETE="off" name="SignonForm" method="post" id="SignonForm" onsubmit="processUnload();" action="login.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="ioBlackBox" value=""/>

    <input type="hidden" name="devicePrint" value=""/>

    <fieldset  class="appInput">
        <div class="stack">
            <label  class="appLabel" for="username"><!-- UserID_JSOSIGNON -->
                User ID
            </label>
        <input id="username" name="username" size="12" maxlength="50" value="" class="userMask soInput" />
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <label  class="appLabel" for="password">
            Password
        </label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" size="12" maxlength="50" value="" class="soInput"/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <INPUT type="IMAGE" value="" src="https://online.citibank.com//JFP/images/spacer.gif" height="1" width="1" onclick="return enterkeySubmit();"/>

</form>

<ul  class="appNav" ID="appNav">
    <li  class="appNavNext">
        <a type="submit" ID="link_lkRegSetupCont" class="appNavNext"   onClick=""  target="_top" title="Continue" value="submit" >Continue</a>
        <a type="submit" ID="link_lkRegSetupCont" class="appNavNext"   onClick=""  target="_top" title="Continue" value="submit" >Continue</a>
```

Comment: `<a type="submit">` is not legal HTML. `type="submit"` is an attribute for `<input>` elements not `<a>` elements. Can you explain what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: anchors don't have a type property. I think you are either thinking of <input type=submit>

Comment: I don't think `<a>` has ever been a valid submission mechanism...

Comment: links don't submit forms... atleast not without using js. use an `input type='submit'`? you'll also need your input to be within the form tags

Comment: i mean how i can make the submit like word

Comment: tried this not working  <a type="submit" value="submit" >Continue</a>

Comment: did you read the comments above?

Comment: yes i did and i tried not working